# Should code be inside user control or the form using it

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small design question which I couldn't find relevant google hits for some reason.

I have a user control which I use in my application. 
The main form opens a second form as a dialog. T
his second form is using the user control which includes a list box.

Naturally I want to preserve the list box items when the forms dispose so I am keeping a private list in the main form.

```
List<string> _listofFirstCoordinates = new List<string>();
```

Now the question is, should the dialog form be the one responsible for relaying the list to the main form or should the code be in the user control?

Should the one populating the list be the user control

```
lst_Coordinates.Items.AddRange(ListOfCoordinates.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

or should the form using it populate it (The subform)

```
uc_EditCoordinates.ListOfCoordinates = ListOfCoordinates;
```

Also is it feasible to just have the user control be a public variable for the form holding it so it may be changed directly or would that be bad design?

Edit:
By the way, the data is saved for now in variables going back and forth between the forms as the user has to finish all subforms before submitting and finally saving it to the database. So it is a

```
var _listofFirstCoordinates = new List<string>();
```

going back and forth.

Comment: This may be more suited in Code Review, I think. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "correct" solution is to abstract-away the View-level concern (in this case, anything to do with `Form`, `UserControl`, and UI controls) away from the Controller and Model-level concerns (in this case, your application's data).

Without completely rearchitecturing your system, you can still apply this separation-of-concerns within your example.

You can conceptually argue the "code-behind" of your `MainForm` class acts as a *kind of* Controller (purists would disagree). It *will* have to know about creating the child form, but it does not need to know about the user-control hosted within the child form - that would be the concern of the child form's.

I suggest defining a class that represents a ViewModel - albeit as we're using WinForms we will use it as a kind of crude "one-way" ViewModel, like so:

```
class MainForm : Form {

    private void ShowChildFormModal() {

        ChildViewModel vm = new ChildViewModel();
        vm.CoordinatesList = ...
        vm.OtherData = ...

        ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
        child.LoadFromViewModel( vm );
        child.ShowDialog();
        child.SaveToViewModel( vm );

        SaveToDatabase( vm );
    }
}

class ChildViewModel { // this is a POCO
    public List<String> CoordinatesList;
    public Int32 OtherData;
}

class ChildForm : Form {

    public void LoadFromViewModel(ChildViewModel vm) {

        // save time and trouble by using the List as a datasource directly, or you can manually populate the combobox as well
        this.childUserControl.LoadFromViewModel( vm ); 

        this.someOtherControl.Value = vm.OtherData;
    }

    public void SaveToViewModel(ChildViewModel vm) {
        // completing this is an exercise for the reader
        // but basically copy values from the controls on the form into the `vm` instance
    }
}

class ChildUserControl : UserControl {

    public void LoadFromViewModel(ChildViewModel vm) {
        this.comboBox.DataSource = vm.CoordinatesList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I should've added that as the data is saved for now in variables going back and forth between the forms as the user has to finish all subforms before submitting and finally saving it to the database.

So it is a var _listofFirstCoordinates = new List<string>(); going back and forth.

Does that change anything in your response?

Comment: @AngelicCore The ViewModel-pattern still applies, in fact it will make your job easier because a single ViewModel instance can represent the state of an entire collection of forms (regardless of their visibility).

Comment: @AngelicCore I've amended my answer to demonstrate how to persist data.